# How to make my main form pause execution for 1 second then continue in c#?

Tags: c#, winforms

I am creating a card game and I need a methods execution to pause  while a card is being animated accross the screen. Currently I have this and it animates the card fine but will carry on playing the game whilst the card is being animated. Not sure how to go about it. I have tried Thread.Sleep() but it still continues all execution possible and then pauses.

```
private void btnPlay_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                string input = Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction.InputBox("Please enter your betting amount (£3.00 minimum bet)", "Play", "3.00", -1, -1);
                bet = double.Parse(input);
                if (Globals.Balance > bet)
                {
                    btnHit.Enabled = true;
                    btnStick.Enabled = true;
                    Globals.Balance -= bet;
                    lblBalance.Text = Globals.Balance.ToString();
                    Play();
                }
                else
                {
                    throw new Exception("You don't have enough money!");
                }

            }
            catch (FormatException)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Incorrect format for betting amount");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }

private void Play()
        {
            ClearDetails();
            DealPlayerCard();
            Classes.Deck.NextCard(Deck);
            DealPlayerCard();
            UpdatePlayerTotal();
        }

    private void DealPlayerCard()
            {
                //does stuff here

                switch (cardNum)
                {
                    case 3:
                        pb.Location = new Point(120, 0);
                        timerCard.Enabled = true;
                        timerCard_Tick(null, null);
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        pb.Location = new Point(180, 0);
                        timerCard.Enabled = true;
                        timerCard_Tick(null, null);
                        break;
                    case 5:
                        pb.Location = new Point(240, 0);
                        timerCard.Enabled = true;
                        timerCard_Tick(null, null);
                        break;
                }
                AddPlayerCard(pb);
                AddToHand("Player");
            }

    private void timerCard_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                this.SuspendLayout();
                //sets x and y in a switch statement here

                if ((CardBack.Location.X == x) && (CardBack.Location.Y == y))
                {
                    timerCard.Enabled = false;
                    CardBack.Visible = false;
                    CardBack.Location = new Point(775, 247);
                    this.ResumeLayout();
                }
                else if ((CardBack.Location.X > 417) && (CardBack.Location.Y < 434))
                {
                    CardBack.Location = new Point(CardBack.Location.X - 1, CardBack.Location.Y + 1);
                    timerCard_Tick(null, null);
                }
                else if ((CardBack.Location.X > 417) && (CardBack.Location.Y == 434))
                {
                    CardBack.Location = new Point(CardBack.Location.X - 1, CardBack.Location.Y);
                    timerCard_Tick(null, null);
                }
                else if ((CardBack.Location.X == 417) && (CardBack.Location.Y < 434))
                {
                    CardBack.Location = new Point(CardBack.Location.X, CardBack.Location.Y + 1);
                    timerCard_Tick(null, null);
                }
            }
```

Comment: Can you edit your post to include where `DealPlayerCard` is called? If it's an event handler you can mark it `async void` and use `await Task.Delay(1000);`

Comment: I have edited, It also gets called from a btnHit event handler as well as the btnPlay

Comment: You are doing a lot in the click handler that should not be done there. I am afraid suggesting a better architecture would be really too broad, though. Maybe you should be looking into how to layout games of that type. I guess you'd want some sort of queue or scheduler to make things happen when they should.

Answer (score 1):

Enabling the timer returns immediately, and the timer events occur separately, which is why you see the game continuing.

Instead move the rest of the game to the timer event, after the animation is finished. Like this (pseudocode):

```
private void DealPlayerCard()
{
    //does stuff here
    timer.Enabled = true;
    // no more code
}

private void timerCard_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     switch (location)
         case first:
             DoSomeStuff();
         case next:
             DoSomeOtherStuff();
         case finished:
             timer.enabled = false;
             continueGame();
 }
```

I guess you have some sort of game loop that wasn't in the sample, which you may also have to pause.

Comment: Generally correct in the root explanation, however note this will not work as intended as "continueGame" would execute in the context of the timerThread and not in the mainThread. Generally speaking it would be better to use a completely different approach for "rendering" stuff in the screen.

Comment: @JorgeCórdoba: Timer events happen on their own thread? Can you explain this more? What if an event handler on the "timer thread" accesses an apartment object?

Comment: I agree - but a better solution would involve knowing about the main game loop. I think I'd set that to some `animating` status, and then the timer could reset it to `playing`, or something like that.

Comment: @EricLippert good point, I was thinking on System.Threading.Timer which does but given this is a winforms application maybe not.

Comment: @JorgeCórdoba: As the documentation for System.Threading.Timer notes, **you must not use it in a winforms application because it will call the UI objects back on the wrong thread**.  You say "maybe not", but we have no evidence at all that the user has deliberately chosen (poorly) to use the thread pool timer instead of the timer that comes with Windows Forms.

Comment: @EricLippert, as I've already noted, I was thinking on a different kind of timer and that's why I put the comment. Etiquette please, I do not appreciate you going out of your way to point out I was wrong when I have already acknowledged that fact. We will later on complain that new users feel unwelcomed on SO

Comment: @JorgeCórdoba: The notion that it is impolite to correct an error on a site dedicated to correctly answering user questions is a strange one; there's nothing rude about pointing out an error. In this and all such cases I am professionally interested to learn how it is that people come to their beliefs about programming, because that helps me design better object models, better documentation, and so on, that prevents possible errors before they begin. Can you say a bit about why you thought that a windows forms app might be using a threading timer?

Comment: @JorgeCórdoba: I also note that at no time did I say you were wrong; if you're embarrassed for some reason, that's not on me. So far all I've done is (1) asked you to explain why a timer would call back on the wrong thread, (2) confirmed that using a threading timer in winforms is documented as wrong, and (3) pointed out that I've seen no evidence that the user is doing it wrong. None of those things are accusing you of any wrongdoing, so it is odd to me that you'd think that. You seem to be getting defensive, but there's no attack.

Comment: @EricLippert I did not, that was the point. I assummed it was a Threading.Timer since I haven't worked with WindowsForms in 8 or 9 years so by default I was thinking on the kind of timer I have used the most. When you pointed it out I simply acknolwedged that fact, that I was thinking of a different kind of timer. Maybe not was a way of saying "maybe what I said before was wrong and he's likely using a winforms timer"... Converstation should have ended there, any additional comments after I acknolgedge the error are going to come off offensive and get me deffensive, that's just basic nature.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186716/discussion-between-jorge-cordoba-and-eric-lippert).

Comment: @JorgeCórdoba: The person telling another person they are behaving wrongly here is *you*, not me; shouldn't I be the one getting offended? (Believe me, I'm not, but maybe we have different "basic natures".) Regardless, I appreciate you explaining your mental processes to me. I am sometimes called upon to design analyzers that detect errors such as the one you described, and it helps to have a model of how different people believe those errors can happen. Thanks!

Comment: @EricLippert let's leave it a that